# Remove underline from Input component Material UI (v1.0 Beta)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using the `Input` component from React Material UI library ([v1.0 beta](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/component-api/input)), I am trying to remove the underline that is rendered using a pseudo element.

```
const styleSheet = createStyleSheet('searchInput', () => ({
    underline: {
        '&:before': {
            height:0
        }
    }
}));

const SearchInput = ({ classes, placeholder, value, onChange }) => {
    return (
        <Input
            classes={classes}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            value={value}
            onChange={onChange} />
    );
};
```

When I try to target `&:before` though, I get the below error. What is the correct way to override styles and remove this underline?

> Warning: Material-UI: the key
>   `.searchInput-underline-1572343541:before` provided to the classes
>   property object is not implemented in Input.
>
> You can only overrides one of the following:
>   root,formControl,inkbar,error,input,disabled,focused,underline,multiline,inputDisabled,inputSingleline,inputMultiline,fullWidth,label
>   + .MuiInput-formControl-583691922,.MuiInput-inkbar-171024778:after,.MuiInput-inkbar-171024778.MuiInput-focused-2315792072:after,.MuiInput-error-3674946725:after,.MuiInput-input-3582851417::-webkit-input-placeholder,.MuiInput-input-3582851417::-moz-placeholder,.MuiInput-input-3582851417:-ms-input-placeholder,.MuiInput-input-3582851417::-ms-input-placeholder,.MuiInput-input-3582851417:focus,.MuiInput-input-3582851417::-webkit-search-decoration,label
>   + .MuiInput-formControl-583691922 > .MuiInput-input-3582851417,label + .MuiInput-formControl-583691922 >
>   .MuiInput-input-3582851417::-webkit-input-placeholder,label +
>   .MuiInput-formControl-583691922 >
>   .MuiInput-input-3582851417::-moz-placeholder,label +
>   .MuiInput-formControl-583691922 >
>   .MuiInput-input-3582851417:-ms-input-placeholder,label +
>   .MuiInput-formControl-583691922 >
>   .MuiInput-input-3582851417::-ms-input-placeholder,label +
>   .MuiInput-formControl-583691922 >
>   .MuiInput-input-3582851417:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,label +
>   .MuiInput-formControl-583691922 >
>   .MuiInput-input-3582851417:focus::-moz-placeholder,label +
>   .MuiInput-formControl-583691922 >
>   .MuiInput-input-3582851417:focus:-ms-input-placeholder,label +
>   .MuiInput-formControl-583691922 >
>   .MuiInput-input-3582851417:focus::-ms-input-placeholder,.MuiInput-underline-892978022:before,.MuiInput-underline-892978022:hover:not(.MuiInput-disabled-265053423):before,.MuiInput-underline-892978022.MuiInput-disabled-265053423:before

Answer (score 59, accepted):

As per **[DOC](https://material-ui.com/api/input/#props).**

> **disableUnderline prop =>**
>
> disableUnderline  :   boolean
>
> Default Value: false
>
> Details: If true, the input will not have an underline.

There is a property `disableUnderline` provided by the DOC, we can directly use that to remove the underline from input element.

Try this:

```
<Input
     disableUnderline={true}     //here
     classes={classes}
     placeholder={placeholder}
     value={value}
     onChange={onChange} />
```

Comment: what if override that underline?

Answer (score 0):

The way to remove the underline form the Textfield of Material UI is to use the css property example borderBottom: 'none !important'

More elaborated view..
'& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
borderBottom: 'none !important'
}

Answer (score -4):

put css a tags to app.css, it work for me. because it use base tags 
a {
        text-decoration: none
    }

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: The underline is not a text decoration. It's a border-bottom, so this wouldn't even work.